# using if statement with list comparison

Tags: python

Here is my problem: on reading a book on networking programming for python, i stumbles across this code:

```
import socket, sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

if sys.argv[1:] == ['server']:
    s.bind('127.0.0.1', PORT)
    ...
    ...
```

and so on. My question is whether the if statement checks if any of the elements in the sys.argv list(except the first item) is compared to be equal to 'server'. I tried doing this in IDLE for Python 3.2 and it didn't work. The book is intended for python 2.7 so I tried that too but it still dint work.

Answer (score 3):

No, it checks whether the list formed by the [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) `1:` is equal to the list `['server']`.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the program, which is stripped. `sys.argv[1:]` - all the command line arguments provided to the program.

The `if` statement checks that your script received only one argument `server`.

Answer (score 3):

No, that wouldn't work in any version of Python. The only thing that does is to check that `sys.argv` from position 1 onwards has only one element, which is `'server'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `'server'` argument whith this construction:

```
if 'server' in sys.argv[1:]:
    do_something()
```

For future, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for get command line arguments.